# Can't set text to the TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, displayobject

I am learning to develop apps for android from a book and after following the instructions I end up with the following. When I run the app the text from the `setStartUpScreenText()` object is not displayed.

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void setStartupScreenText(){
        TextView planetNameValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DataView1);
        planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hey post your activity class here

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `setContentView` method before updating any view in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `setStartupScreenText()` method after `setContentView` in oncreate of the activity

Comment: Stupidly I forgot to add that. However, after I did and tried to run it, I got an error (Unfortunately, Hellow_World has stopped working. The code worked before but some desired text was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all call the `setStartUpScreenText()` function from inside of `setStartUpWorldValues()` function (either in the beginning or in the end). You can also call this function inside the `onCreate()` methods after the `setStartUpWorldValues()` function.

Secondly replace the entire code of the `setStartUpScreenText()` function with the following code: (page 90, Learn Android App Development, publisher: Apress)

```
            TextView planetNameValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    TextView planetMassValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
    planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
    TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
    planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
    TextView planetColoniesValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
    planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
    TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
    planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
    TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
    planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
    TextView planetBaseValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
    planetBaseValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
    TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
    planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));
```

Answer (score -1):

protected void setStartUpWorldValues() {

```
    earth.setPlanetColonies(1);  //Set planet colonies to 1
    earth.setPlanetMilitary(1); // set planet military to 1 
    earth.setColonyImmigration(1000); // set planet population to 1000 
    earth.setBaseProtection(100);   // set Planet armed force to 100
    earth.turnForceFieldOn();  // Turn on the planet force field

 setStartUpScreenText() ;
    TextView planetNameValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    TextView planetMassValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
    planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
    TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
    planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
    TextView planetColoniesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
    planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
    TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
    planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
    TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
    planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
    TextView planetBasesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
    planetBasesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
    TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
    planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));      
}
private void setStartUpScreenText() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```